# Space in which a vector and its opposite vector are identified

Tags: vector-spaces, metric-spaces, geometric-topology

I have a set of points in an n-dimensional space and need a mapping so that the euclidean distance between two points $p_1$ and $p_2$ where $p_1 = - p_2$ is zero (or small).
Anyone has an idea how to approach this?

Comment: You want more or less to "amalgamate" 2 opposite vectors. There is a way to do that,  that I describe in $\mathbb{R^3}$: work systematically in the upper hemisphere (in $\mathbb{R^n}$, the equivalent is the set of vectors that have their last coordinate $\gt 0$). A special treatment has to be done for vectors with $x_n=0$.

Comment: Doing that you work in $\mathbb{PR^n}$, the **projective space** associated with $\mathbb{R^n}$, and you do **projective geometry**. Technically, you can also add systematically add an $n+1$st component which is in your case $+1$ or $-1$ in order to preserve (by setting this information aside) the sign information.

Comment: Define the distance between two points as $d(p_1,p_2)=\min(\|p_1-p_2\|,\|p_1+p_2\|)$.

Comment: @JeanMarie That was the first thing i tried. The problem is the special case you mentioned. I am actually trying to find clusters made up of nearby vectors, and with this method two vectors where $x_n$ is close to zero might end up in very different clusters.

Comment: @Rahul I need a space in which the **euclidean** distance between the opposite vectors is low.

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify the goal. Apparently, you want a map $F$ from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to another Euclidean space such that $F(x)-F(-x)$ is either identically zero or is very small.  What other properties do you want $F$ to have? After all, we could just map $F(x)= (|x_1|, |x_2|, \dots,|x_n|)$.